# Evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^{n+1}}{(1^{1\over n}+2^{1\over n}+\dots+n^{1\over n})^n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits

> Evaluate $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^{n+1}}{(1^{1\over n}+2^{1\over n}+\dots+n^{1\over n})^n}.
> $$

I know it's easy to find the answer  $e$， but I wanna collect some good ways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $x\to x^{1/n}$  is increasing in $[0,+\infty)$, it follows that
$$\frac{n^{1+1/n}}{1+1/n}=\int_{x=0}^{n}x^{1/n}\,dx\leq 1^{1\over n}+2^{1\over n}+\dots+n^{1\over n}\leq \int_{x=1}^{n+1}x^{1/n}\,dx=
\frac{(n+1)^{1+1/n}-1}{1+1/n}.$$
Hence
$$\frac{1}{(1+1/n)^n}\leq \frac{(1^{1\over n}+2^{1\over n}+...+n^{1\over n})^n}{n^{n+1}}\leq \frac{((n+1)^{1+1/n}-1)^n}{n^{n+1}(1+1/n)^n}=
\frac{((1+1/n)^{1+1/n}-1/n^{1+1/n})^n}{(1+1/n)^n}$$
As $n$ goes to infinity, the left-hand side and the right-side tend to $1/e$. Therefore the given limit is $e$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my way:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n^{1\over n}-1\sim\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln n}{n}\\ n!\approx\sqrt{2n\pi}({n\over \mathrm e})^n      $$So we have:\begin{align}
  \lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}
{\left(1+\frac{1^{1\over n}+2^{1\over n}+...+n^{1\over n}-n}{n}\right)^{\left(\frac{n}{1^{1\over n}+2^{1\over n}+...+n^{1\over n}-n}\right)(1^{1\over n}+2^{1\over n}+...+n^{1\over n}-n)}}\;\;\;\; \\ =\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{\exp[1+1^{1\over n}+2^{1\over n}+...+n^{1\over n}-n]}\\=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{\exp[\frac{1}{n}\left(\ln1+\ln2+...\ln n\right)]}\\=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}} =\mathrm e
\end{align}

Comment: nice solve, good job

Comment: This solution is not convincing. All we know is that $\lim_n (1+1/n)^n = e$. You can't just do what you did in your solution

Comment: Take $f(n)=y$ and remember that $y\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: But we have $n$ in the numerator also...

Comment: I understand @mathworker21's concern that we need be more careful. To avoid a potentially dangerous argument of taking partial limit, notice that $$ a_n := \sum_{k=1}^{n} (k^{1/n} - 1) = \frac{\log (n!)}{n} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\log^2 n}{n}\right) $$ So $$ \frac{n}{\left(1+\frac{a_n}{n}\right)^n} = \frac{n}{\exp\left( a_n + \mathcal{O}(\frac{a_n^2}{n}) \right)}=\frac{n}{\exp\left(\frac{\log(n!)}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)\right)}. $$ This justifies the above computation.

Answer (score 2):

Another quick way to see it by [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Special_cases)

$$\frac{n^{n+1}}{(1^{1\over n}+2^{1\over n}+\dots+n^{1\over n})^n}= \frac{n}{\left(\frac{1^{1\over n}+2^{1\over n}+\dots+n^{1\over n}}{n}\right)^n}\sim \frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}} \to\mathrm e
$$